T3 stack, Next.js with Next-Auth: Redirecting to Login Page Despite Successful Authentication
I'm working on a project using Next.js version 14 and integrating authentication with Next-Auth credentials provider. However, I've encountered an issue where despite successful authentication, the application doesn't redirect to the protected pages as expected. Instead, it keeps redirecting back to the login page.
Here's a summary of the problem:
Issue: After successful authentication, the application should redirect to protected pages but redirects back to the login page. This is working fine in development mode but the problem occurs in production when hosted using vercel.
Expected Behavior: Upon successful authentication, the user should be redirected to the desired protected pages.
Observations:

The authentication process seems to be successful as cookies are being set.
The problem lies in the redirection to the protected pages after authentication.
This is working fine in development mode but the problem occurs in production when hosted using vercel.

I've included my auth.ts file and middleware.ts file below for reference.
auth.ts file
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
   pages: {
      signIn: loginUrl,
   },
   session: {
      strategy: "jwt",
//... more code ....

middleware.ts file
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = {
   matcher: [/* required paths here */],
};

Any insights into why this issue might be occurring and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
